# Use Of Restriction in EJBQL for Seam

Tags: seam-conversation

I am very new to Seam, I need some clarification in this below code , I need to know how it works, what is use of RESTRICTIONS in this code .......

```
package org.domain.pixel.action;

import org.domain.pixel.entity.*;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Name;
import org.jboss.seam.framework.EntityQuery;
import java.util.Arrays;

@Name("projectList")
public class ProjectList extends EntityQuery<Project> {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = -7673337640345325071L;

 private static final String EJBQL = "select project from Project project";

 private static final String[] RESTRICTIONS = { 
  "lower(project.processOwner) like lower(concat(#{projectList.project.processOwner},'%'))",
  "lower(project.projectName) like lower(concat(#{projectList.project.projectName},'%'))",

   }; 

 private Project project = new Project();

 public ProjectList() {
  ;
  setEjbql(EJBQL);
  setRestrictionExpressionStrings(Arrays.asList(RESTRICTIONS));
  setMaxResults(25);
 }

 public Project getProject() {
  return project;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is a standard approach in Seam to create a backing bean (or "action") for views that are list-based. The `ProjectList` creates a result set based on the JPA query (called "EJBQL"), and the restrictions are a a means to dynamically create a WHERE clause for this query, for instance based on user input.

The user input is most likely placed in the instance var called "`project`". The restrictions (2 in total) select only records (from the table corresponding to the Project entity class) for which the `processOwner` AND the `projectName` are equal to the `processOwner` AND the `projectName` set in "`project`" (based on a case-insensitive comparison).